# General algorithm to restrict a placement in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I want to place elements in a n*n matrix. The restriction is that there are at most m elements allowed on every diagonal. I can't think of a general way to express this restriction. Anyone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diagonals (m=n-1):

```
0 1 2 . . . m
1 2 . . . m .
2 . . . m . .
. . . m . . .
. . m . . . .
. m . . . . .
m . . . . . 2m
```

These can be represented by an array, diag1[2*(n-1)].

Here's the other direction:

```
m . . . . . 2m
. m . . . . .
. . m . . . .
. . . m . . .
2 . . . m . .
1 2 . . . m .
0 1 2 . . . m
```

These can be represented by a similar array, diag2[2*(n-1)].

Example 5x5 matrix:

diag1[2*(n-1)] represents the following diagonals...

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

diag2[2*(n-1)] represents the following diagonals...

```
4 5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4
```

Both of these arrays and the following functions should be added to your matrix class, assuming you have one.

```
addElement(element_ *elementptr, int x, int y)
{
   if (diag1[x+y] < maxDiag1 && diag2[x+(n-1)-y] <maxDiag2) {
      diag1[x+y]++; 
      diag2[x+(n-1)-y]++;
      matrix[x][y] = elementptr;
   } else {
      // show error message?  return 0?  etc.
   }
}

remElement(int x, int y)
{
   if (matrix[x][y] != NULL) {
      diag1[x+y]--;
      diag2[x+(n-1)-y]--;
      matrix[x][y] = NULL;
   } else {
      // show error message?  return 0?  etc.
   }
}
```

Comment: Slight change in the code.  Problem stemmed from array indices being, in reality, 0 to (length-1) rather than being 1 to length.  An example was also added.